# ClickOnce version not updating

Tags: winforms, installation, clickonce

My ClickOnce application is currently on version 2.0.0.12. I updated the application, changed the published and assembly version to 2.0.0.13. When I start the application on a client desktop it checks for an update but does not recognize an update is available and runs as normal.

I launch fidler and watched the request and the manifest it is pulling back still has the 2.0.0.12 version reference.

On the server I deleted the 2.0.0.12 version all together, turned off caching on the server and uninstalled the app from the desktop.

When I launch the installer it fails downloading files because it can't find the 2.0.0.12 version folder. I updated the Application.htm, Setup.exe and .application files on the server and they reflect the correct 2.0.0.13 version.

My question is: Where the heck is the ClickOnce app getting the reference to the previous version from?

Here is the error log:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows                 : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime : 4.0.30319.17020
    System.Deployment.dll   : 4.0.30319.17020 built by: FXM3REL
    clr.dll                 : 4.0.30319.17020 built by: FXM3REL
    dfdll.dll               : 4.0.30319.17020 built by: FXM3REL
    dfshim.dll              : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : {URL_REMOVED}\AlphaManager.application
    Server                  : Microsoft-IIS/7.0
    X-Powered-By            : ASP.NET
    Deployment Provider url : {URL_REMOVED}\/install/AlphaManager.application
    Application url         : {URL_REMOVED}\/install/Application%20Files/AlphaManager_2_0_0_12/AlphaManager.exe.manifest
    Server                  : Microsoft-IIS/7.0
    X-Powered-By            : ASP.NET

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : AlphaManager.application, Version=2.0.0.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4bf6f9c465057aee, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity    : AlphaManager.exe, Version=2.0.0.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4bf6f9c465057aee, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of {URL_REMOVED}\/install/AlphaManager.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading {URL_REMOVED}\/install/Application Files/AlphaManager_2_0_0_12/Microsoft.mshtml.dll.deploy did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Answer (score 5):

Under you project properties, click the Updates button....

[image]

And then make sure you've set the correct minimum required version. This number does NOT automatically update like your other publish version number:

[image]

Comment: This is unlikely to be the problem. Logs in the question appear to be referencing the correct .application file, and then go on to request Application Files from 2.0.0.12. This suggests the new .application file referencing 2.0.0.13 was never downloaded. Perhaps due to a stale cache, as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the setup files on internet was cached.

To resolve this problem you can create .htaccess file on the installation folder on the internet

Edit the file and add this example and change your file names for index.html and .application file

```
>  FileETag None Header unset ETag Header set
> Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" Header
> set Pragma "no-cache" Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00
> GMT"   FileETag None Header unset ETag
> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store,
> must-revalidate" Header set Pragma "no-cache" Header set Expires "Wed,
> 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSrHJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like ClickOnce doesn't realize it installed v12 of the application, or it only partially installed it, or (more likely), you have the publish properties set to be online-only. Make sure that is set to online/offline.

If this still doesn't fix your problem, uninstall the application and reinstall it, then try publishing v14 and see if it picks it up.

Make sure you don't have the updateURL set (assuming you want it to pick up updates from the same URL used for installation, as is usually the case).

I don't believe making it a required update will fix your problem. It doesn't sound like it's accessing the right manifest. I would also make sure it is looking for the deployment manifest (.application file) in the top folder of your deployment directory, and NOT the one under the versioned folders (application files/yourapp_1_1_1_12/yourapp.application). Are you publishing directly from VS, or are you creating the manifest manually/programmatically another way?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with internet cache, it was using the .application from the cache of the proxy (corporative lan), and it was not downloading the new content....

when I turned on the minimum version, stoped working...

so I asked IT if they could help me, and they did... and no more problems after...

Comment: So, is your answer to get IT to help you?

Comment: my problem was about the internet cache... not clickonce... this is fact, because in other places it works fine...